# How to bind paramenters to SQL IN() clause dynamically?

Tags: php, data-binding, mysqli

**searchValue** comes from ajax search bar.
Example value: **Chickens are fat**

```
//Turns search value into array and counts elements. Or words in the string
$explode = explode(' ', $searchValue); //value = Array (chickens, are, fat)
$tags_cnt = count($explode); //value = 3

$cnt_q = NULL;
$s_cnt = NULL;
for ($i=0; $i<$tags_cnt; $i++) {

    //$cnt_q finds number of '?' needed for SQL
    $cnt_q = $cnt_q. '?';
    if ($i<$tags_cnt - 1) $cnt_q = $cnt_q.','; //value = ?,?,?

    //$s_cnt finds Number of 'S' for paramater binding
    $s_cnt = $s_cnt. 's'; //value = sss
}

//Turns the Array into comma separated string for Bindparam.
$tags=NULL;
    foreach ($explode as $tag) {
    $tags = $tags."'".$tag."',";
}
$tags = trim($tags, ",");// value = 'Chickens', 'are', 'fat'


//The IN clause = IN(?,?,?)
IN (".$cnt_q.")

//prepared binding statments = $stmt->bind_param('sss','chickens','are','fat');
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param($s_cnt, $tags);
```

I can't see why this is not working.

I have the correct amount of '?' needed for the SQL query.

I have the correct amount of 's' needed for the bind_param function.

I have the correct format of the search value: 'chickens', 'are', 'fat' for the bind_param function.

My error message:
**Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in ... line number**

**Below is full code:**

```
//retrive search value from ajax
$searchValue=$_GET["searchValue"];


//connect
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    echo "Our apologies, having technical difficulties";
}

//assign tags, turn searchValue into a array by each word
$explode = explode(' ', $searchValue);
$tags_cnt = count($explode);

$cnt_q = NULL;
$s_cnt = NULL;
for ($i=0; $i<$tags_cnt; $i++) {

    $cnt_q = $cnt_q. '?';
    if ($i<$tags_cnt - 1) $cnt_q = $cnt_q.',';

    $s_cnt = $s_cnt. 's';
}

$tags=NULL;
foreach ($explode as $tag) {
    $tags = $tags."'".$tag."',";
}
$tags = trim($tags, ",");


//search by Tags 
$query = "  SELECT results.Title, results.tags
        FROM results
        INNER JOIN tags
        ON results.ID = tags.book_id 
        WHERE tags.tag 
        IN (".$cnt_q.")
        GROUP BY results.ID";


$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param($s_cnt, $tags);
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo "Title: ";
        echo $row["Title"];
        echo "</br>";
        echo "Tags: ";
        echo $row["tags"];
        echo "</br></br> ";
    }



$stmt->close();

$conn->close();
```

Comment: What is the result when you dump your query?

Comment: The number of $s_cnt are different from $tags. Have you tried to print the count of them both?

Comment: yea. I've printed them out and they are the same. I get: sss - ?,?,? -'chickens', 'are', 'fat'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, it should work just fine:

`$searchValue=$_GET["searchValue"];`
`//connect`
`$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);`
 `if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    echo "Our apologies, having technical difficulties"; }`

`//assign tags, turn searchValue into a array by each word`

`$explode = explode(' ', $searchValue);
$tags_cnt = count($explode);`

`$cnt_q = NULL;
$s_cnt = NULL;
for ($i=0; $i<$tags_cnt; $i++) {`

`$cnt_q = $cnt_q. '?';
    if ($i<$tags_cnt - 1) $cnt_q = $cnt_q.',';`

`$s_cnt = $s_cnt. 's';`

`}`

`$tags[] = & $s_cnt;`

`for ($a=0; $a<$tags_cnt; $a++) {
     $tags[] = &$explode[$a];
    }`

`//search by Tags`

`$query = "  SELECT results.Title, results.tags
        FROM results
        INNER JOIN tags
        ON results.ID = tags.book_id 
        WHERE tags.tag 
        IN (".$cnt_q.")
        GROUP BY results.ID";`

`$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $tags);
$stmt->execute();`

`$results = $stmt->get_result();
     while($row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo "Title: ";
        echo $row["Title"];
        echo "</br>";
        echo "Tags: ";
        echo $row["tags"];
        echo "</br></br> ";`
    `}`

`$stmt->close();`

`$conn->close();`

Comment: Did not work. Pretty sure you need same number of ? and S for every paramater. So three words needs three ? and three S.

Comment: What is the error that you get when you try my way? I've done tests on my server and it is working just fine without errors.

Comment: If more than one word is entered it won't work. Example: 'Chicken' works. But 'ABC chicken' does not work.

Comment: I edited my answer and I think now it will work the way you want.

Comment: Thank you. Works. Gonna fiddle with it and see why it works. Gotta wait 22hr for the bounty.

Comment: Error that you are getting in your code is because when you use bind_params you must put as much variable as S and ? marks you have in your code. so proper binding looks like that `bind_params('sss', $tag1, $tag2, $tag3)` but in your code it was like `bind_params('sss', $tags)` I didn't explain it verry good, but I guess you get what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

try this code without unnecessary loops

```
$seachValue = isset($_GET['searchValue']) ? $_GET['searchValue'] : '';
if (!$seachValue) {
    exit('Empty search value');//Your error text
}

$values = explode(' ', $seachValues);
$size = count($values);

$markers = $params = array();
$markers = array_pad($markers, $size, '?');
$params = array_pad($params, $size, 's');

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    exit('Our apologies, having technical difficulties');
}

$query = 'SELECT results.Title, results.tags
    FROM results
    INNER JOIN tags
    ON results.ID = tags.book_id 
    WHERE tags.tag 
    IN (' . implode(',', $markers) . ')
    GROUP BY results.ID';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
if (!$smtp) {
    exit('Our apologies, having technical difficulties');//Your error text
}

$tags = array(implode($params));
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; ++$i) {
     $tags[] = &$values[$i];
}

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $tags);
$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->get_result();
if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
    foreach ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo sprintf('Title: %s<br>Tags: %s<br><br>', $row["Title"], $row["tags"]);
    }
}
else {
    echo 'Nothing found';
}

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```